# Is it good practice to always wait on a task to complete?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Sorry if it is a dumb question. I'm confused about the `wait()` and its variants in regards to the task parallel library.

Every single example I've seen waits on tasks to complete - is this considered good practice?

My scenario is this, that I'm developing a windows service that will run continuously. I would like to engage a number of tasks, but I don't care if they will run to completion - I will set a cancellation-token with an expiration, that will throw an error if something goes awry. So I don't see the need for a wait-to-complete, but every darn example uses it...

Comment: 1. look up what `wait()` does in the docs 2. "do i need this?" 3. yes->use it, no->dont use it

Comment: Do you care about exceptions possibly thrown inside each task, and how they propagate? It may not work the way you expect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303

Comment: @TimCastelijns I can - and have - studied the documentation. Yet I'm still confused - hence the question. I'm obviously not competent on the level as you, but please consider the notion that this forum is used by many different people, some - as myself - less capable than others.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for that - I had not considered that, but now will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your situations needs. If for instance, you want to launch a sub process to do a procedure, say for instance, fire off an email in parallel you can do without waiting.

However, if you will need to *act* upon what ever result or structure which is affected by some behavior you will need to wait.

If your tasks are self contained and do not interact and/or depend on each other, then I do not see why you would need to wait.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to wait on a task if the code that is waiting requires the output of the task before it can proceed. If you don't need that output, don't wait.

Comment: I wish I could share the credit for the answer, as they're both satisfactory to me. I actually drew a literal straw to select the one to be marked. Thanks a lot for you answer, too.