# Getting Task results from synchronous execution

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm having a hard time understanding `async` and the corresponding behavior.  This is a model of the program I'm trying to write, and a repro of the problem I'm having:

```
namespace AsyncTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting....");
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.DoSomeWork();
            Console.WriteLine("ending....");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public bool DoSomeWork()
        {
            return GetTrue().Result;
        }

        Task<bool> GetTrue()
        {
            return new Task<bool>(() => true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the `GetTrue().Result` call, it never returns.  My `Task<bool> GetTrue()` method is a dummy method for repro purposes, but I'm not quite sure why it never comes back.  But it returns if I have this:

```
namespace AsyncTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting....");
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.DoSomeWork();
            Console.WriteLine("ending....");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public async void DoSomeWork()
        {
            await GetTrue();
        }

        Task<bool> GetTrue()
        {
            return new Task<bool>(() => true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, with my repro I want the initial behavior.  I don't want `async void` for the calling method.  I want to be able to return `bool` from my calling "normal" method.  How can I achieve this?  How can I get the first example to run and actually return the `bool` from `DoSomeWork()`?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Thank you for the answers.  I think what the problem is, is that my `GetTrue()` method isn't a true repro.  In my method, I'm not generating the actual `Task<bool>` object.  It's really a call to `Task.Factory.FromAsync<bool>()` that is creating the `Task<bool>` object.  And it's that task that I don't know how to "start".  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Your edit changes the concept of the question. If you're  trying to block (with `task.Result`) on the result of `FromAsync`, you'd need to clarify what is the actual context of this code. Is it really a simple console app, or perhaps, it is a WinForms / WPF / ASP.NET app? Then it might explain why are you're having a deadlock. Check Stephen Cleary's blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Noseratio Sorry, the context is a WCF service.  The `Task.Factory.FromAsync<bool>()` call is wrapping the `Begin...()` and `End...()` functions that the service has pushed to the consumer.  But I see no way to actually start the task and it just hangs.

Comment: So this is still the *client-side* where you call a WCF service? If so, it still matters what kind of app is this client-side app.

Comment: @Noseratio That's correct, it is the client-side making the WCF call.  The client-side app is a Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: This is a frequent mistake, I've updated my answer with more details about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
Task<bool> GetTrue()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

instead of:

```
Task<bool> GetTrue()
{
    return new Task<bool>(() => true);
}
```

In the latter case, you don't even start the task you create. You'd need to start it with `Task.Run` or `Task.RunSynchronously`. Usually you don't create tasks directly via `new Task()`. Check Stephen Toub's ["Task.Factory.StartNew" vs "new Task(...).Start"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx?Redirected=true) and ["Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might be tempted to do this:

```
Task<bool> GetTrue()
{
    return Task.Run(() => true);
}
```

However, usually this turns to be a known-anti-pattern, check ["Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)".

**Updated** to address the comments:

> ... the context is a WCF service. The Task.Factory.FromAsync()
>   call is wrapping the Begin...() and End...() functions that the
>   service has pushed to the consumer. But I see no way to actually start
>   the task and it just hangs.
>   ... it is the client-side making the WCF call. The client-side app is a
>   Windows Phone 8 application.

You're experiencing a deadlock on the UI thread, because you're blocking on the result of a pending task (with `task.Result`). The task itself cannot be completed, because the `await` continuation is posted asynchronously to the dispatcher loop of the UI thread of your WP8 app, which is now blocked. Stephen Cleary explains this in great details in [his blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). To avoid this, you should embrace ["async all the way down"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) programming model. It practically means that you should make your UI event and command handlers `async` as well, and do `var result = await task`, rather than `var result = task.Result` in there.

Comment: +1 for the anti-pattern. Stephen Cleary also has a nice blog post on this IIRC. It basically says "let consumers of your API wrap things in Tasks.. don't do it yourself".

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  (Please see my answer edit)  I'm not actually creating the `Task<bool>` (apologies, bad repro I believe).  The `Task<bool>` is getting generated from a call to `Task.Factory.FromAsync<bool>()`.  And it's *that* task that I'm not sure how to "start".  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!  Also, +1.

Comment: @user3175663, see my comment to the question.

Comment: Ok perfect, I'll try that.  With `async` event handlers, though, I thought `async void` was bad practice.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @user3175663, `async void` event handlers are probably the most notable exception of that rule, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19415646/1768303). Just deal properly with [exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303) and [reentracy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2014/03/03/async-re-entrancy-and-the-patterns-to-deal-with-it.aspx) inside `async void` event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start a task before it does anything.. calling `Run` will do that for you:

```
Task<bool> GetTrue()
{
    return Task.Run(() => true);
}
```

This gives the output you expect. `Result` is a blocking call. If your `Task` instance never starts.. `Result` can never return.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  (Please see my answer edit)  I'm not actually creating the `Task<bool>` (apologies, bad repro I believe).  The `Task<bool>` is getting generated from a call to `Task.Factory.FromAsync<bool>()`.  And it's *that* task that I'm not sure how to "start".  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance! +1.