# nunit async/await assertion on synchronous method calling async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, nunit

This (n)unit test fails:

```
[Test]
public void FooTest()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    Assert.That(() => foo.DoSomething(), Throws.InstanceOf<Exception>());
}
```

This is the class under test:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public async void DoSomething()
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
    {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            throw new Exception("exception");
        });
    }
}
```

If I change `DoSomething` this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
}
```

Then the test will pass. Is there any way I can avoid having to do that?

Note: I *cannot* change the signature of `DoSomething` to `public async Task DoSomething()`, as I cannot change the `IFoo` interface, as that comes from a 3rd party library.

Comment: No. You're stuck with `Task.Wait()`. If the interface can't change that's going to be a problem. Doing async over sync is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using `async void` like this, unless you don't care about the result of .`DoSomethingAsync` and [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369179/tap-global-exception-handler) exceptions are thrown inside `async void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer, as other commenters have noted, is to not use `async void`. One of the main problems with `async void` is that there's no easy way to detect completion or retrieve results (success/exceptions) from an `async void` method. So, unit testing `async void` methods is a real pain.

Since you have an unchangeable `IFoo` interface and you need an asynchronous equivalent, consider adding an `IFooAsync` interface:

```
public interface IFooAsync : IFoo
{
  Task DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

Then always implement `IFoo.DoSomething` as an explicit implementation that just awaits `DoSomethingAsync`. This is similar to the approach I take for [asynchronous `ICommand` implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Your third-party library will only use the `IFoo` interface, while your unit tests (and other code) can use `IFooAsync`.

If, for some reason, this solution is unpalatable, you *could* unit test `async void` methods by explicitly giving them a context. I have an [`AsyncContext` in my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) that should work for this:

```
[Test]
public void FooTest()
{
  var foo = new Foo();

  Assert.That(AsyncContext.Run(() => foo.DoSomething()),
      Throws.InstanceOf<Exception>());
}
```

However, I recommend using the `IFooAsync` approach; I think it's a cleaner design anyway.