# Cause an Application.UnhandledException from a Task

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, winrt-async

This is an odd scenario, but I have a `Task` in an unknown state. What I'd like to do is to be able to if it becomes `Faulted` then cause an `Application.UnhandledException`. Rather than `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` which is what happens if I leave it alone.

`await task` does work however this code needs to run in .NET 4 without any extra dependencies. So in essence I need to recreate the effect of `await`ing the task.

```
task.ContinueWith(t => {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
    SynchronizationContext.Current != null ? TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() : TaskScheduler.Current
);
```

The above code doesn't seem to do anything at the moment.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.  Minus anybody being able to repro your problem from that snippet and you for some mysterious reason not using the return value of ContinueWith.  Something like task = task.ContinueWith(...)

Comment: Can you give more context? When do you expect the `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown? on which thread?

Comment: What I'd like is the `InvalidOperationException` to happen on the UI thread and show up as an `Application.UnhandledException`.

Comment: You can get close by enabling `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` in `app.config` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303). Note however `UnhandledException` will still be fired upon garbage collection rather than right on the spot (where exception was thrown).